# How to get the handle of the splitter between docked forms

Tags: delphi

I docked two forms on a panel.

It will create a splitter automatically.

Is it possible to get the handle of the splitter using code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to get the handle of that control. Splitter controls descend from `TGraphicControl`, so they do not have window handles.

Whatever your reason for wanting a handle, you'll need to find some other solution to the problem you thought it would solve.

Comment: I hope to get the size of two form when the splitter is moving

Comment: @arachide It's always best to ask about the problem rather than your hypothesised solution. Likely we could have solved your problem if you'd asked about it.